# How to pop up a view controller on top?

Tags: iphone, ios, model-view-controller, modalviewcontroller

Situation: 
In have lot of view controllers in my app and they are presented as navigation or modal view controllers. The app communicates with the server from almost all the screens. I want to show a login screen to the user when his/her credentials are expired. I want to present the login screen as a modal on top of the current view on the screen and dismiss it as soon as login is successful. 
I have really no idea how can I achieve this. If there is a modal view displayed on the screen by some view controller and login screen is also required to be presented as a modal, from where should I do this. I tried switching rootViewController of the window in appDelegate but it didn't work well and also messed up lot of things. Please provide me suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your problem. The best way in my opinion is to have a simple class, say `LoginHandler.h` and keep it around during the lifetime of the app.

You do not have to initialize it when the app starts. You can implement a handy trick to always get the same instance of this class when you need it:

```
// @interface
+(id)sharedHandler;

//@implementation
+(id)sharedHandler {
   static id sharedHandler = nil;
   if (sharedHandler == nil) {
      [sharedHandler = [[LoginHandler alloc] init];
   }
   return sharedHandler;
}
```

Now you simply get the shared instance with `[LoginHandler sharedHandler]`, similar to the user `NSUserDefaults` or `UIApplication`.

You can have a method like

```
-(BOOL)renewLoginFromViewController:(UIViewController*)controller`;
```

that presents a model view controller with something like this:

```
[controller presentModalViewController:loginScreen];
```

and returns `YES` if the login was successful (or it does not disappear before the login worked out.)

You could handle all your login logic from this class. It would be a nice textbook example for *[encapsulation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Articles/ooObjectModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005149-CH5-SW10)*.

Comment: Then please check the check mark ;-).

Comment: Out of curiosity and not having anything to do with the question at hand, is this the standard way of having a shared object of a certain class?

Comment: @esqew It certainly works very well. It is the so-called *singleton* design. It is very useful for things like in-App purchase monitoring, network status, background imports, etc,

Answer (score 2):

Check out `UIViewController`'s [`presentViewController:animated:completion:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a) method to present modal views (as long as you're not building for iOS <5.0).

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good thing to check it only when app launches. This way it is recommended to do this on your AppDelegate.m on didFinishLaunchWithOptions.

You can do something like that:

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
if (USER_HAS_VALID_CREDENTIALS) {
    self.viewController = [[[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
} else {
    self.viewController = [[[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease]; // need to get credentials
}
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Remember to launch the RootViewController from LoginViewController after successful login.